# Python : POST a Multipart-Encoded File

Tags: python-requests, postman

Trying to upload a file using requests module, but encountered Internal Server Error Its the same using poster module too:

```
import requests
url = "abc.com/upload"
querystring = {"ft":"1","fn":"filename"}
payload = ""
files={'file': open(r'Users/.../test.zip', 'rb')}
headers_info = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---12345",
    'x-api-service-version': "1.0",
    'connection': "Keep-Alive",
    'authorization': "Basic XXXXXXX",
    'x-file-format': "decrypted",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }

response = requests.post(url, data = payload , headers=headers_info , params=querystring , files=files)

print response.status_code
print response.text
```

I tested the api with POSTMAN (chrome extension to test rest API) and it seems to work fine with postman i get a success response and the file is uploaded.

The postman code for python shows :

```
import requests
url = "abc.com/upload"
querystring = {"ft":"1","fn":"filename"}
payload = ""
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---12345",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'x-api-service-version': "1.0",
    'connection': "Keep-Alive",
    'authorization': "Basic XXXXXXX",
    'x-file-format': "decrypted",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "XXXXXXX"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Any suggestions for the same ? Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for any pointers you can share!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738525/python-requests-how-to-add-content-type-to-multipart-form-data-request/39742334#39742334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify `'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---12345",` as well as empty `data`. Try to send request without `headers`

```
response = requests.post(url, params=querystring , files=files)
```

If you fail you might try to add `'authorization': "Basic XXXXXXX", 'postman-token': "XXXXXXX"` headers