# multipart POST with python requests unsupported media type

Tags: python

Trying to recreate the following cURL with Python requests. I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415084/multipart-data-post-using-python-requests-no-multipart-boundary-was-found) that I "should NEVER set `"content-type": 'multipart/form-data'`" header. Instead, allow requests module to do it.

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://example.com/v1/endpoint' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN_HERE>' \
  -F 'name=test5' \
  -F 'type=notebook' \
  -F 'content=@some-file.json;type=application/json'
```

Here is my code:

```
headers = {
  "accept": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN_REDACTED>"
}

with open(path, mode="r") as f:

    data = f.read()

    stuff = {
        "name": "test1",
        "type": "notebook",
        "content": f"{data};type=application/json"
    }

    upload_resp = requests.post(
        url="https://example.com/endpoint",
        data=stuff,
        headers=headers
    )

    return upload_resp
```

With this I get an HTTP `415` code: `Unsupported media type`.

When I set `headers` as:

```
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN_REDACTED>",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
}
```

I get an HTTP `400` with: `Missing initial multi part boundary` which makes sense as we are setting the content-type not requests so it'll be invalid (as per linked SO thread above).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send file using POST from a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script) Your request made using curl has `content` as a file upload, while in your Python code you're sending the file's content as form data.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I now seem to be oscillating between 431 and 'code': 400, 'message': 'Content-Type header must be set for multipart part.'

Comment: Ahh this worked: ```upload_resp = requests.post(
            url=f"https://example.com/v1/endpoint",
            params=parameters,
            files={"content": ("temp.json", data, "application/json")},
            headers=headers
        )
```
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39742334/9997385